# How do I get the property path from Utf8JsonReader?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, system.text.json

With NewtonSoft, we could get the path with `reader.Path`. System.Text.Json does not have this.

```
namespace API.JsonConverters
{
    using System;
    using System.Text.Json;
    using System.Text.Json.Serialization;

    /// <summary>
    /// Use DateTime.Parse to replicate how Newtonsoft worked.
    /// </summary>
    /// <remarks>https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/datetime/system-text-json-support</remarks>
    public class DateTimeConverterUsingDateTimeParse : JsonConverter<DateTime>
    {
        public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            try
            {
                return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(), styles: System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
            }
            catch (FormatException)
            {
                // We have to do this to have the Path variable auto populated so when the middleware catches the error, it will properly populate the ModelState errors.
                // https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to#error-handling
                // https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/release/3.1/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Formatters/SystemTextJsonInputFormatter.cs#L79
                throw new JsonException("Invalid DateTime. Please use RoundTripKind (MM-DD-YYYY) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values");
            }
        }

        public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, DateTime value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
        {
            writer.WriteStringValue(value.ToString("o"));
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get access to the current path so that I can throw an exception that has both a custom message and a [`Path`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception.path?view=net-5.0) from within the `Read()` method of my custom `JsonConverter`?

Comment: [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs) doesn't seem to track the path at all.  All it tracks is the stack of container types (object or array) in a [`BitStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/BitStack.cs) with [`Utf8JsonReader._bitStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8b38c1973eeaf1c13e8d2729ab1b1fe1a7cf9a5b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs#L225).

Comment: `JsonSerializer` does track this information using [`ReadStack.JsonPath()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8b38c1973eeaf1c13e8d2729ab1b1fe1a7cf9a5b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs#L227). Unfortunately `ReadStack` is internal and not made available publicly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within a [`JsonConverter`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1), you want to throw a custom exception with a custom message and also include JSONPath information.  As explained by the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json-converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-5-0#jsonexception), `System.Text.Json` only appends path information to an exception of type [`JsonException`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonexception) - and only when the exception has no message.  So, how can the path information be included?

The obvious way to do this would be to get the current path from within [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read) and pass it to your exception's constructor.  Unfortunately, **`System.Text.Json` does not make the path available to [`Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read) or [`Write()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.write)**.  This can be confirmed by checking the [reference source](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/tree/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json).  **[`Utf8JsonReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs) currently does not even know the path.**  All it knows is the stack of container types (object or array) using a [`BitStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/BitStack.cs) member [`Utf8JsonReader._bitStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8b38c1973eeaf1c13e8d2729ab1b1fe1a7cf9a5b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs#L225), which is the minimum necessary to handle its state transitions correctly when exiting a nested container.  [`JsonSerializer`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/JsonConverterOfT.ReadCore.cs) does track the current stack, via the [`ReadStack`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs) ref struct which has a [`JsonPath()`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/8b38c1973eeaf1c13e8d2729ab1b1fe1a7cf9a5b/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Serialization/ReadStack.cs#L227) method.  Unfortunately `ReadStack` is internal and never exposed to applications or to `Utf8JsonReader`.

As a workaround, you could create nested exceptions with the inner exception being your required exception type and the outer exception being a `JsonException` into which the serializer will populate the path.  The following is one example of how to do this:

```
public override DateTime Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    try
    {
        return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(), 
                              styles: System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind); 
    }
    catch (FormatException)
    {
        var innerEx = new ProblemDetailsException("Invalid DateTime. Please use RoundTripKind (MM-DD-YYYY) - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/how-to-round-trip-date-and-time-values");
        throw new JsonException(null, innerEx);
    }
}
```

Then at a higher level you could catch the `JsonException` and throw an outer  `ProblemDetailsException`, e.g. like so:

```cs
public class JsonExtensions
{
    public static T Deserialize<T>(string json, JsonSerializerOptions options = default)
    {
        try
        {
            return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(json, options);
        }
        catch (JsonException ex) when (ex.InnerException is ProblemDetailsException innerException)
        {
            var finalException = new ProblemDetailsException(innerException.Message, ex.Path, ex);
            throw finalException;
        }
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Here I as assuming `ProblemDetailsException` looks something like:

  ```
  public class ProblemDetailsException : System.Exception
  {
      public ProblemDetailsException(string message) : base(message) { }
      public ProblemDetailsException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) { }
      public ProblemDetailsException(string message, string path) : base(message) => this.Path = path;
      public ProblemDetailsException(string message, string path, Exception inner) : base(message, inner) => this.Path = path;

      public string Path { get; }
  }
  ```
- You might consider parsing your `DateTime` using [`CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.cultureinfo.invariantculture?view=net-5.0):

  ```
  return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(), 
                        styles: System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, 
                        provider: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
  ```

  As written currently, your converter will function differently in different locales.  Or, if you really want to parse in the current locale, make that explicit in your code:

  ```
  return DateTime.Parse(reader.GetString(), 
                        styles: System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, 
                        provider: System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
  ```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/HsV2JD).

Comment: I essentially need the path in the converter so I can instead through a custom exception with the path in it so my API returns the proper ProblemDetailsException. Right now, when there is a 400 bad request, the ModelState errors are serialized and returned with error properties like `$Property`. When you throw a JsonException, and its returned, its returned with a period `$.Property`.

Comment: @VictorioBerra - Then you may need to do that at a higher level.  Where the call to `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` is made, you can catch the `JsonException` and throw your own exception using the `Path` of the caught exception.  The path is simply not passed into `JsonConverter<T>.Read()` at all so you can't do it there, you can't even get it from `Utf8JsonReader` using reflection because it isn't stored there.

Comment: @VictorioBerra - for more conformation, see the comments for [`internal sealed class JsonReaderException`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/JsonReaderException.cs): *This class exists because the serializer needs to catch reader-originated exceptions in order to throw JsonException which has Path information* -- the implication being that the reader doesn't have the Path information.

Comment: ill go ahead and accept this, but I think the real issue here is that System.Text.Json is missing a lot of the convenience features we had in Netwonsoft and this is yet another one. I understand your workaround but its a lot of boilerplate for something that should not be so difficult. Also, I do not understand why its inconsistent with the way the ModelBinder loads up error paths. IE: Why the `$.Prop` VS `$Prop`?

Comment: @VictorioBerra  - I agree it's missing a lot of stuff.  As to your second comment, `$.Prop` strictly conforms to [JSONPath syntax](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) while `$Prop` does not.  In JSONPath syntax, `$` represents the root element and `.` represents the child operator so `$.Prop` means *The child of the root that is named "Prop".*  `$Prop` is missing the child operator so doesn't strictly mean anything, which I reckon is why MSFT chose `$.Prop`.  Could also be an instance of the left hand not knowing exactly what the right hand is doing...