# I need to modify the value of string type if the property name is "xyz" in JsonConverter<string> using System.Text.Json

Tags: c#, .net, .net-7.0, system.text.json

I don't want to decorate my properties with this converter like

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(CustomJsonConverter))]
public string xyz {get;set;}
```

I need to use it like this

```
JsonSerializerOptions _options = new()
{
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
    Converters = { new CustomJsonConverter() }
};

var result = JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(stream, _options);

public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string>
{
    public override string Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
         if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
         {
             var propertyName = reader.GetString();

             if (propertyName == "xyz")
             {
                  reader.Read(); // Move to the property value
                  string originalValue = reader.GetString();

                  // Modify the string value (e.g., add a prefix)
                 string modifiedValue = "Modified: " + originalValue;

                 return modifiedValue;
            }
        }

        return reader.GetString();
    }

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string value, JsonSerializerOptions options)
    {
        // Write the value as a string
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
    }
}
```

reader.TokenType is always equals to JsonTokenType.String so it never goes in that if statement

```
if (reader.TokenType == JsonTokenType.PropertyName)
```

Comment: The converter doesn't know anything about the parent context so you can't get the property name.  For confirmation see e.g. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137258/3744182) to [How do I get the property path from Utf8JsonReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69136510/3744182): *Unfortunately, System.Text.Json does not make the path available to `Read()` or `Write()`.*  But does it have to be a converter?  Could it be a custom contract resolver?  Also, what .NET version are you using?

Comment: working with .net7, unfortunately I can't add any contract/attributes etc on the DTO, client wants to define the property for masking at runtime, so I was thinking to intercept at deserialization and do it.

Comment: If you are in .NET 7 then you can use a typeinfo modifier.  Typeinfo modifiers are entirely runtime and don't require any modifications to the DTO types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [.NET 8](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v8.0.3/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs) or [.NET 9 Preview 2](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/v9.0.0-preview.2.24128.5/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs) there is no way get the parent property name or any other part of the serialization path inside [`JsonConverter<T>.Read()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.read) because it is not known by [`Utf8JsonReader`](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/blob/main/src/libraries/System.Text.Json/src/System/Text/Json/Reader/Utf8JsonReader.cs).  For confirmation, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69137258/3744182) to *[How do I get the property path from Utf8JsonReader?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69136510/3744182)*.  And as you have seen, by the time `Read()` is called the reader has been advanced past the property name.

Instead, in [.NET 7 and later](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/system-text-json-in-dotnet-7/#contract-customization) you can use a [typeInfo modifier](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver.modifiers) to programmatically apply the converter to any .NET property named `xyz`.  To do this, first create the following modifier and converter:

```
public static partial class JsonExtensions
{
    public static Action<JsonTypeInfo> AddPropertyConverter(JsonConverter converter, string propertyName) => typeInfo =>
    {
        // Use StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase if you want to apply the comparer to properties named Xyz and XYZ also.
        foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties.Where(p => converter.CanConvert(p.PropertyType)
                                                           && String.Equals(p.GetMemberName(), propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
        {
            // If you only want to apply the converter only when there is not one already, use ??=
            // property.CustomConverter ??= CustomJsonConverter.Instance;
            property.CustomConverter = CustomJsonConverter.Instance;
        }
    };

    public static string? GetMemberName(this JsonPropertyInfo property) => (property.AttributeProvider as MemberInfo)?.Name;
}

public class CustomJsonConverter : JsonConverter<string?>
{
    public static CustomJsonConverter Instance { get; } = new(); // Cache a single instance for performance

    public override bool HandleNull => false; // Change to true if you want to modify null string values.

    public override string? Read(ref Utf8JsonReader reader, Type typeToConvert, JsonSerializerOptions options) =>
        "Modified: " + reader.GetString();

    public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, string? value, JsonSerializerOptions options) => 
        // Write the value as a string
        writer.WriteStringValue(value);
}
```

Then in .NET 8 and later apply the modifier to your desired [`IJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.ijsontypeinforesolver) using [`WithAddedModifier()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsontypeinforesolver.withaddedmodifier):

```
string propertyName = "xyz";

JsonSerializerOptions _options = new()
{
    // Configure either a DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver or some JsonSerializerContext and add the required modifier:
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
        .WithAddedModifier(JsonExtensions.AddPropertyConverter(CustomJsonConverter.Instance, propertyName)),
    // Add other options as required
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,             
};
```

Or in .NET 7 create and configure a [`DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.defaultjsontypeinforesolver?view=net-7.0) directly as follows:

```
string propertyName = "xyz";

JsonSerializerOptions _options = new()
{
    TypeInfoResolver = new DefaultJsonTypeInfoResolver()
    {
        Modifiers = {JsonExtensions.AddPropertyConverter(CustomJsonConverter.Instance, propertyName)}
    },
    // Add other options as required
    DefaultIgnoreCondition = JsonIgnoreCondition.WhenWritingNull,
    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,             
};
```

Now all properties named `xyz` of type `string` will have their value remapped by your converter during deserialization as required, without needing to add attributes to, or otherwise modify, your serialization classes.

Notes:

- If you want properties with a `null` value to be remapped, you must override [`HandleNull`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonconverter-1.handlenull) and return `true`.
- If you want to remap properties with a specified JSON name instead of a specified .NET name, check [`JsonPropertyInfo.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.name) instead of `GetMemberName()`:

  ```
   foreach (var property in typeInfo.Properties.Where(p => converter.CanConvert(p.PropertyType)
                                                      && String.Equals(p.Name, propertyName, StringComparison.Ordinal)))
  ```

Demo fiddles for .NET 8 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Hgw0gd) and .NET 7 [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzLGU8).

Comment: it's not able to find the property if its buried in a generics<Collection<T>> e.g.
PagedResult<MyResponse> it looks like this  
public class PagedResult<T>
{
 public IReadOnlyList<T> Items { get; set; }

 public int FilteredCount { get; set; }

 public int TotalCount { get; set; }
}

Comment: @dnxit - I'm not sure what you mean by that, can you share a [mcve], possibly as a new question?  I tried the specific case shown in your question of a modifiable property `public string xyz {get;set;}` in a nested class and it seems to work, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/fzLGU8.

Comment: you're right, I checked the fiddle, my json looks like this 
{
  "items": [
    {
      "id": "string",
      "name": "string",
      "userCount": 0,
      "tenantId": "3fa85f64-5717-4562-b3fc-2c963f66afa6",
      "tenantName": "string",
    }
  ],
   "totalCount": 0
}
let's say I want to modify the value of tenantName

Comment: @dnxit - then I would request a [mcve] demonstrating the problem, possibly as a second question or alternatively as a forked fiddle.

Comment: @dnxit - the `string name` should be the C# property name not the JSON property name which might have been mangled by some naming policy like `JsonNamingPolicy.SnakeCaseLower`.  If `tenantName` is the JSON name not the C# name, modify `AddPropertyConverter()` to check [`JsonPropertyInfo.Name`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.metadata.jsonpropertyinfo.name) instead of `GetMemberName()` or use `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` as noted in comments if you want to ignore case entirely.